# Getting the value of a variable into a textbox android

Tags: android

I am new to android.
I have a `Button` on screen which when pressed, increments the value of a variable.
I converted this `Integer` into a `String`, and now made a `TextView`.
I want to display the value of the `String` in the `TextView` but am unable to figure out how, any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: have you ever tried `textBox.setText()`

Comment: I checked the question earlier but that didn't resolve my problem. Turns out my problem was that I placed certain part of the code in the wrong place, that fixed it. Thanks :) And, sorry for the duplicate O:)

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
textBox.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //Define the TextView
    private TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //get and set value
        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text1);
        tv1.setText("new value");

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_text1”
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in `activity_main.xml` ,you must set id for TextView first,then you can use the id in `MainActivity.java`